# Razor Pages async task return to modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm new in Razor Pages and I can't really find a solution on my problem.

I have a modal, where I would like to update the Identity Roles(Add/Remove users). The async task works fine and I have the list for the members and nonmembers, but the modal close itself after the post.
How I can prevent it(modal close) what is the correct return in this case?

C#

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddtoRoleAsync()
{
    if(Input != null) 
    { 
    ToolboxRoles role = await _RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.Id);
    List<ToolboxUser> members = new List<ToolboxUser>();
    List<ToolboxUser> nonMembers = new List<ToolboxUser>();
    foreach (ToolboxUser user in _UserManager.Users)
    {
        var list = await _UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name) ? members : nonMembers;
        list.Add(user);
    }

        Input.Role = role; 
        Input.Members = members;
        Input.NonMembers = nonMembers;
    }
    return Page(); //I don't know what is the correct return action here, so the modal stay showed
}
```

Function calling:

```
                           <form method="post">
                                <button asp-page-handler="AddtoRole" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default" data-id="@item.Id" data-name="@item.Name" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#EditRole" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    Update
                                </button>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="EditRole" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #ffd800">
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:left">Update Role</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#ffd800,#fff)">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="modal_name" asp-for="Input.RName" />
                    <input type="text" id="modal_id" asp-for="Input.Id" />
                    @if (Model.Input != null)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: radial-gradient(#ffd800,#fff);border: 1px solid #f11322;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <h4 id="modal_text1" class="font-weight-bold" style="color: #f11322;"></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                            @if (Model.Input.NonMembers.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                <tr><td colspan="2">All Users Are Members</td></tr>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @foreach (ToolboxUser user in Model.Input.NonMembers)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="AddIds" value="@user.Id">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </table>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: radial-gradient(#ffd800,#fff);border: 1px solid #f11322;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <h4 id="modal_text2" class="font-weight-bold" style="color: #f11322;"></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                            @if (Model.Input.Members.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                <tr><td colspan="2">All Users Are Members</td></tr>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @foreach (ToolboxUser user in Model.Input.Members)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DeleteIds" value="@user.Id">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </table>
                    }
                    <button asp-page-handler="UpdateRoles" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS which I use to pass the values to the modal:

```
$('#EditRole').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var id = button.data('id');
    var name = button.data('name');  // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // Update the modal's content
    document.getElementById('modal_id').setAttribute('value', id);
    document.getElementById('modal_name').setAttribute('value', name);
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#modal_text1').text('Add Users to ' + name);
    modal.find('#modal_text2').text('Remove Users from ' + name);
});
```

Thanks,
Devcore

Comment: First read documentation: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).
 `return Page()` you should call when you want to refresh page. If everything is OK after add (you are sure that Add is performed) you can just: `return Ok()`, or `return NoContent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should separate the modal body and make it as a partial view. Use jquery ajax to get the partial view, append it to the modal then open it.

I made a simple demo, you may refer to it.

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<button id="Edit" data-id="1" class="btn btn-danger"
        data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    Update
</button>

<div id="EditRole" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #ffd800">
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:left">Update Role</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#ffd800,#fff)">
            
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Edit").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Index?handler=AddtoRole',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                },
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.modal-body').html(result);
                    $('#EditRole').modal('show');
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Student Input { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    
    public IActionResult OnPostAddtoRole()
    {
        Input.Name = "StudentA";
        return Partial("_AddRolePartial",Input); 
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {

    }
}
```

**_AddRolePartial.cshtml:**

```
@model RazorTest.Models.Student

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Id:</label>
        @Model.Id
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        @Model.Name
    </div>
    <button asp-page-handler="UpdateRoles" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Student.cs:**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: For some reason the modal never show. I tried with "error: funciton(result)" just to check if that is the reason, and it is. I checked the POST and it's triggered I also checked if the token is valid and it was. what did i do wrong?

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking. It works. Thank You for the help. So far this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

`return Page()` you should call when you want to refresh page. If everything is OK after adding to list (you are sure that Add is performed) you can just: `return Ok()`, or `return NoContent()`.

Read documentation: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to see the whole picture (how your modal is handling the return response from your `OnPostAddtoRoleAsync()` function).

as [Lazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13448436/lazar-%C4%90or%C4%91evi%C4%87) pointed out, What would be more beneficial is to return a response on whether the users were added to the roles correctly. Using `Ok()` or other various status codes depending on what happened to the users would be more beneficial in this instance.

You can prevent certain actions from taking place inside the modal by using `event.preventDefault();`. Again, we can't see how your frontend razor page is handling the modal since you have not provided that here. This source might help with using modals https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/349/razor-pages-and-bootstrap-modal-master-details

Let me know if this helps, thanks.

Comment: I updated my original post with a little bit more info. Sorry but I'm absolute new in Razor Pages.

Comment: @Devcore no worries! I believe my answer still applies here. You'll want to return more useful `status codes` when you update a user instead of sending `Page()` back which will just refresh or re-enter the page. This closes the modal and returns you to the beginning of the page which is not something I think you want to do.

Comment: @Devcore Look here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ for more information on modals. And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601923/submitting-data-from-a-bootstrap-modal-popup on how to submit requests using a modal.